# Software methodologies based on partial unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

Considering that there are so many names for so many software methodologies out there, I would like to know if there is any recommending only partial unit testing.

I am a TDD believer, but sometimes I get the feeling of these two things:

1. Most of the thinking for a better and more maintainable structure/design is achieved mostly with the first tests of a class.
2. Unit tests are more important when working on someone else code

Therefore I suppose that out there, some people is writing about their experiences using a mid approach. I would like to do some self research on the topic and find out if I can get a "plan B" when pushing some TDD practices.

Is there any software methodology or trend based on partial unit testing?

Comment: I'd argue against #2: Unit tests are essential when refactoring any code, regardless of who wrote it or when.

Comment: sadly I am not a gifted programmer and I am initially slower when working on a new project I have never seen before. I am much more likely to do mistakes and to not be aware of side effects. Specially because of those side effects on modules I have never seen, I do appreciate so much more having unit tests as a safety net. I still love though unit tests, but I want them so much more if touching something I have never seen before. Many of the programmers I have met are also more concerned about unit tests when starting on new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [characterization tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test) on legacy code which capture the actual behavior of the code. Here's a good demo of the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4dlF0kcThQ